# Имитировать клик на линк в емайле при автоматическом тестировании

Tags: веб-программирование, java, junit, тестирование, mockup

Пишу автоматические интеграционные тесты для сайта. Использую java, junit и Сахи.

По сценарию тест должен послать пользователю емайл с линком, на который тот должен кликнуть для дальнейшего действия. Если тест проходит автоматически, то этот клик надо как-то сымитировать.

В линке передаются токены, то есть просто перейти на страничку не получится. Как это правильно делается? Что мне почитать по этому поводу (желательно на русском)?